# Regarding Installation of ubuntu sdk

Tags: application-development

I'm very eager in developing mobile apps for ubuntu. I followed the instruction given in the http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/ website. but i could not install completely. was gving error regarding qt. saying qmlscence executable is not found. however i followed the instruction to manually configure it. But there was nothing under opt/ directory. i'm having ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You missed something. The description on the cited site requires Ubuntu 12.10. Please upgrade your system first, then you will have no trouble installing the packages. The problem is caused by the `Qt4`, which is used by Ubuntu 12.04. What you can try to remove every package related to `Qt4`, and see if it will work like that.

(There are also some  conflicting packages like `qdbus, qt4-dev-tools, libqt4-dev, etc.`, in my case, so I've gived it up removing them...)

Comment: Thanks Frantique. Prior to this i had installed ubuntu 12.10 which often crashed. so i reverted back to 12.04. So can you please tell me how to install this in 12.04. that would be great.

Comment: I have faced the same problem like you, I still did not found a solution yet to install it on 12.04, but even now I am working on it.

Comment: See my updated answer.